# Don't know Ubuntu username and password

Tags: users, user-profile

I installed my Ubuntu today and I logged out but now it asks for username and password which I never set up. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

How did you not set a password?

You can reboot into single user mode to reset the password:

1. Reboot
2. When the bootloader loads, press e
3. find the "kernel line", it starts with `linux /booot/...`
4. Delete the characters:
   `ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff`
5. Replace them with
   `rw init=/bin/bash`
6. Press x to boot
7. At the command prompt type `passwd {YourUsername} and enter your new password.
8. Reboot and user the password you just set.